# ProGuard package name shortening

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I'm working on an Android project which is automatically run through ProGuard when I package it for distribution.

With the Android default settings, ProGuard obfuscates the class and package names to mostly single letters, but keeps the package hierarchy around. So, if I for example have a package like

`com.example.foo.bar.something.else.my.class.net`

that contains come class `Blah`, ProGuard will turn this into something like

`a.b.b.c.a.c.a.a.b.a`

where the last `a` stands for the class name `Blah`.

Is there some switch that tells ProGuard to collapse the entire package hierarchy into a single identifier, i.e turn the above example into something like `dw.a` instead where `dw` stands for `a.b.b.c.a.c.a.a.b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

[`-flattenpackagehierarchy`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#flattenpackagehierarchy)

without providing a *package_name* does the trick.